# Access logs show +210k mentions of localhost IP as origin of request

Tags: centos7, lets-encrypt, httpd.conf

I have a CentOS 7 server, with 5-6 domains (one being the main domain, the others subdomains).

Ever since installing Lets Encrypt and handling the redirections in `httpd-vhost.conf`, the access log has been filling up with requests from localhost / my server's IP. Using this:

`cat /var/logs/domains/example.com-access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 1`

yields **214,900 requests** made by the server to itself. In comparison, the next top number of requests (Googlebot) is between 1,000 and 2,000.

The requests look something like this (* used as placeholder for my server's IP)

`*.*.*.* - - [26/Aug/2021:03:44:10 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2017/04/myimg-01.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 125763 "-" "-"`

Is this normal behaviour? I have Lets Encrypt and redirections on other servers (same OS, same settings), and this isn't happening there.

If this isn't normal behaviour, what can I do to find out the root cause of it?

Comment: why are you hiding localhost ip? 127.0.0.0/8 is known by the whole internet and yes that could be correct in case of an reverse proxy setup

Comment: @djdomi Because it's not showing as 127.0.0.1, it's showing the way it would if I were to remotely ping any of the domains on that server. For example, let's say that my server's real IP is 123.456.789.012. That's what shows up in the access logs.

Comment: well to answer your questions, you have to show your vhosts else we won't get further deeper into the situation